# Groovy regex find and replace

Tags: regex, groovy

I have a groovy value like the following:

"hostname blah blah blah"

When that occurs, I want to keep the hostname, but delete everything after it including the first space.

I'm having difficulty with the regex. Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide examples? What is hostname? Is it an IP? Is it a name? What are the valid characters? What have you tried?

Comment: And what have you tried? Have you read [ask]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extract the hostname and/or a part of a string by a regular expression can be done in a straightforward way.

If the values are separated by whitespace then can just split the string by a space character and use the first part. Split() method takes in a regular expression as its first argument.

```
String s = "hostname blah blah blah"
String[] parts = s.split(' ', 2)
if (parts) {
  println parts[0]
  s = parts[0] // if want to replace the variale s with just the hostname
}
```

Here is an alternate example using a regular expression to pull out the hostname part of the string value. The first part of the regular expression `(\S+)` is looking for a sequence of non-whitespace characters. For a set of possible hostnames, a stricter expression could be something like `(\w+(\.\w+)*)`.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher
if (s =~ /^(\S+)\s/) {
  println Matcher.lastMatcher.group(1)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That put me on the right path. I was looking for just the first word if there were multiple words, I ended up doing this:

if (hostname.contains(" ")){
hostname = hostname.substring(0, hostname.indexOf(" "))
}